# HTML5 - Canvas Radial Gradient shape edge

Tags: html, html5-canvas

My code:

```
var $c = $('#myCanvas');
$c.attr('width', $(window).innerWidth());
$c.attr('height', $(window).innerHeight() * 0.99);            
var cidx=0;

function redraw() {
    var ctx = $c.get(0).getContext('2d');
    var w = ctx.canvas.width;
    var h = ctx.canvas.height;
    var r = Math.min(w,h)/2;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);

    ctx.beginPath();
    var grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(w/2,h/2, 0.94*r, w/2, h/2, 1*r);
    grad.addColorStop(1, "transparent");
    grad.addColorStop(0.75, "red");
    ctx.fillStyle=grad;
    ctx.arc(w/2, h/2, r, 1.5*Math.PI, 1.5*Math.PI + 1*(0.5*Math.PI));
    ctx.fill();                    
    ctx.restore();
}
```

I getting this result:

[image]

I want to get this result:

[image]

Is here any way to make shape edge in circle?  Without change:

```
ctx.arc(w/2, h/2, r, 1.5*Math.PI, 1.5*Math.PI + 1*(0.5*Math.PI));
```

Because I need showing clock like:

- quater past -  `ctx.arc(w/2, h/2, r, 1.5*Math.PI, 1.5*Math.PI + 1*(0.5*Math.PI));`
- half past - `ctx.arc(w/2, h/2, r, 1.5*Math.PI, 1.5*Math.PI + 2*(0.5*Math.PI));`
- quater to - `ctx.arc(w/2, h/2, r, 1.5*Math.PI, 1.5*Math.PI + 3*(0.5*Math.PI));`
- entire hour - `ctx.arc(w/2, h/2, r, 1.5*Math.PI, 1.5*Math.PI + 4*(0.5*Math.PI));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's starting code for you.

It draws rectangles along the circumference of a circle to give you some "jaggies".

It displays more uniform "jaggies" than your desired image, but you can play with randomizing your width, height and spacing of the rectangles to give it a less uniform result.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle='red';

var n=65;
var cx=150;
var cy=150;
var r=125;
var w=6;
var h=8;
var sAngle=-Math.PI/2;
var eAngle=0;

ctx.shadowColor='black';
ctx.shadowBlur=8;
ctx.shadowOffsetX=1000;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(cx-1000,cy,r-3,sAngle,eAngle);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.shadowColor='rgb(0,0,0,0)';

for(var a=sAngle;a<eAngle;a+=Math.PI/n){
    var x=cx+r*Math.cos(a)-w/2;
    var y=cy+r*Math.sin(a)-h/2;
    ctx.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
}
```

```css
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```